# Autopopulate list when adjacent cell meets criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to find a way to autopopulate a table with multiple cell contents if they have a specific criteria beside them.
For example, a list of names invited to interview, that when I type 'Yes' in their adjacent cell to show they will attend, will autopopulate into a separate full list of names of everyone who has confirmed attendance.
Apologies if this is really simple, I am fairly new to Excel formula!

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you need a separate list? You should be able to filter for all the yes...

Answer (score 0):

I used a formula **=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(B$2:B$11="Yes",ROW($2:$11)),ROW(A1))),"")** to do this.

However, this requires manual modification of the data range. It can not be added automatically, you need to manually pull down the formula to fill the cells below. Maybe there are some simpler ways to solve this problem. For your reference only.

[image]